# concurrent reference counter class and scoped retain: is this ok?

Tags: c++, concurrency

This is a question regarding coding design, so please forgive the long code listings: I could not resume these ideas and the potential pitfalls without showing the actual code.

I am writing a ConcurrentReferenceCounted class and would appreciate some feedback on my implementation. Sub-classes from this class will receive "release" instead of a direct delete.

Here is the class:

```
class ConcurrentReferenceCounted : private NonCopyable {
 public:
  ConcurrentReferenceCounted() : ref_count_(1) {}

  virtual ~ConcurrentReferenceCounted() {}

  void retain() {
    ScopedLock lock(mutex_);
    ++ref_count_;
  }

  void release() {
    bool should_die = false;
    {
      ScopedLock lock(mutex_);
      should_die = --ref_count_ == 0;
    }
    if (should_die) delete this;
  }

 private:
  size_t ref_count_;
  Mutex mutex_;
};
```

And here is a scoped retain:

```
class ScopedRetain {
public:
  ScopedRetain(ConcurrentReferenceCounted *object) : object_(object) {
    retain();
  }

  ScopedRetain() : object_(NULL) {}

  ~ScopedRetain() {
    release();
  }

  void hold(ConcurrentReferenceCounted *object) {
    assert(!object_); // cannot hold more then 1 object
    object_ = object;
    retain();
  }

private:
  ConcurrentReferenceCounted *object_;

  void release() {
    if (object_) object_->release();
  }

  void retain() {
    object_->retain();
  }
};
```

And finally this is a use case:

```
Object *target;
ScopedRetain sr;

if (objects_.get(key, &target))
  sr.hold(target);
else
  return;

// use target
// no need to 'release'
```

Comment: How do you plan to use variable "should_die" in your use case. How and where is this variable updated ?

Comment: "should_die" is simply a local variable in the release method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ConcurrentReferenceCounted` seems to use a full mutex, which is not necessary and not very fast. Reference counting can be implemented atomically using architecture-dependent interlocked instructions. Under Windows, the `InterlockedXXX`family of functions simply wraps these instructions.

Comment: I am writing portable code across Windows, Linux, Embedded linux and Mac OS X: I am not sure I can find interlocked equivalents for all these platforms...

Comment: Keep looking, big difference.  Or you'll end up with a "sucks everywhere" product.

Comment: The linux kernel defines a `atomic_t` data type, which has assembly implementations for many platforms. 

It's up to you and your performance requirements whether it's worth the effort or not.

Comment: Nobody wants to write software that "sucks everywhere" ;-) so I will use an atomic increment, but does this work for "decrement and compare" ?

Comment: If you want an example of a lock-free concurrent counter that works under all the OS's you mentioned, check out the code at the following link.  It's BSD licensed so you can use it however you like:  https://public.msli.com/lcs/muscle/muscle/system/AtomicCounter.h

Comment: Yes, it works - you do `--ref_cnt` using an exchange-and-add operation, which gives you the original value of the reference counter before the decrement. If multiple threads do it concurrently, only one thread gets a previous value '1' in return.

Comment: @Jeremy: Thanks for the link ! Looks great, much more manageable the openpa. I'll try to include it in http://rubyk.org/oscit and will let you know how it goes.